# URLからHTMLを取得すると「ページを表示することができませんでした」と返ってくる

Tags: javascript, python, html, python3

pythonについての質問です。urllib.request.urlopen().read()でページのソースを取得しようとしたのですが、思い通りに取得できません。詳細は以下です。以下のプログラムにより、指定したurlのソースを取得し、"1.txt"に出力しました。

```
import urllib.request

url = "http://www.data.jma.go.jp/obd/stats/etrn/view/10min_a1.php?
prec_no=91&block_no=47945&year=2016&month=8&day=22&view="
html_nodecoded = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
html_decoded  =  html_nodecoded.decode('utf-8')

filename = "1.txt"
fa = open(filename,"w",encoding="utf-8")
fa.write(html_decoded)
fa.close()
```

しかしながら問題ここで問題が起こりました。
正確にhtmlを取得できているか確認するためにページのソースと"1.txt"を比べたところ、一部が食い違っており、正確に取得できていないことがわかりました。
以下は、"1.txt"のうち正確に取得できていなかった部分の近辺を抜き出したものです。

「"1.txt"(説明に必要な部分)」

```
  ..........
  ..(省略)..
  ..........
  <li>１０分ごとの値</li>
  </ul></div>
<!-- //pankuzu menu -->

<div id="main">
<!-- contents -->
<h1 class="print">１０分ごとの値</h1>

<br />ページを表示することが出来ませんでした。<br />ブラウザの「戻る」ボタンをクリ
ックしてください。</div></div></div><div id="footer_area"><div id="nfooter">
<p>気象庁：〒100-8122東京都千代田区大手町1-3-4  代表電話：03-3212-8341</p><ul>
<li><a href="http://www.jma.go.jp/jma/kishou/info/coment.html">気象庁ホームペ
ージについて</a></li></ul></div></div></body></html>
```

取得先のページのソースを確認したところ、ソースコードの一部分が
`<br />ページを表示することが出来ませんでした。<br />ブラウザの「戻る」ボタンをクリックしてください。</div>`
と置き換わってしまっていることがわかりました。

取得先のページのURLは以下です。
http://www.data.jma.go.jp/obd/stats/etrn/view/10min_a1.php?prec_no=91&block_no=47945&year=2016&month=8&day=22&view=

どうすれば正確に取得できるかわからず途方に暮れています。。

実行環境はpython3.7、windows10のコマンドプロンプトです。

Comment: タイトルには質問の概要を書くようにしてください。タグ以上の情報がありません。

Comment: 通常のWebブラウザから同URLにアクセスした場合も、同じメッセージが出るようです。この手の検索結果表示ページでは良く見られる挙動（直接URLアクセスを許容しない）のような気がしますし、そもそもあなたのやりたい事がサイト規約上許可されているかも合わせてご確認ください。

Answer (score 2):

取得しているURLを再度確認してください。
見てみましたがHTTPのリクエストが存在しないだけですよ。
例えば以下なら正しく取得できました。

```
"http://www.data.jma.go.jp/obd/stats/etrn/view/10min_a1.php?prec_no=44&block_no=1133&year=2016&month=8&day=22&view="
```